# Upgrading Ubuntu 15.04 [to 16.04]

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, updates, 15.04, 15.10

I've been trying to update my 15.04 machine to a more recent version, considering 15.04 is no longer supported.

The usual `do-release-upgrade` did not work. It showed that there is an update available (to 16.04, xenial), however, if I tried to run it, I received the following error:

 `An upgrade from 'vivid' to 'xenial' is not supported with this tool.`

After some googling, I've read that I had to upgrade 15.04 to 15.10 first and then to 16.04.

To upgrade to 15.10 I was supposed to use `do-release-upgrade -d`. But it did not do the trick. It said there were no upgrades available.

I have also tried solution suggested at [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release) but with no success. When I manually looked at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ I could not even find files for Vivid nor Wily.

So how could I upgrade my machine? Doing fresh install is really not an option at this point.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As I said, at this point I'd really prefer not to reinstall it from scratch due to amount of configuration required afterwards.

Comment: Does that configuration take days to complete? if not it's still faster to reinstall. Again, there's no guarantee you end up with a functional system (forcing you to reinstall anyway) or about your personal "configurations" being preserved. And if those are so important you should have done the online upgrades in 2015 and 2016. Attempting it in 2017 with such "configuration" pretext is ridiculous.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading)

Answer (score 2):

There is no longer a supported upgrade path from 15.04 to any newer release; you cannot upgrade to 15.10, because it is no longer available from Canonical, and you cannot upgrade to a newer version without that step.  Your only choice is to install clean, with appropriate data preservation steps first.